# Spring JPQL and SIZE function with condition

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have the following method in my repository in Spring Boot app with Hibernate and MySQL db:

```
@Query("""
            SELECT tw FROM TW tw
            LEFT JOIN tw.docks d // where dock has flag isDeleted
            WHERE d.id = :dockId
            AND tw.status <> 'DELETED' AND SIZE(tw.docks) = 1
            """)
```

I want to add some condition to my `SIZE` function to count only `docks` that `dock.isDeleted = false`. Is it possible or I have to write some native query?

EDIT:
adding `ON d.isDeleted = false` is not a solution of course because it doesnt affect `SIZE` function

`TimeWindow` table and `Dock` table are connected with third table `time_window_dock` table

Answer (score 0):

You could write a group by query with an aggregation function:

```sql
SELECT tw 
FROM TW tw
LEFT JOIN tw.docks d ON d.isDeleted = false
WHERE d.id = :dockId
AND tw.status <> 'DELETED'
GROUP BY tw
HAVING COUNT(d.id) = 1
```